# How to add external <script> to <head> section for all mediawiki pages?

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

I want add external script to head section for all pages in mediawiki.

Function `onBeforePageDisplay` callback from [`BeforePageDisplay`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay) hook:

```
//LocalSettings.php
...
# Assign my functions to hook

$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] ='onBeforePageDisplay';

function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin )
{
    mw.loader.load('http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js', 'text/javascript');
    $out->addModules( 'mw.loader' );
    return true;
};
```

In this function i want to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
<script>var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": true }</script>
```

to `<head>` section for all pages in wiki.

For old versions of mediawiki used `addScript` method of [OutputPage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:OutputPage.php) object:

```
$out->addScript( $html )
// Add a JS file. $html is a full script tag: '<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>'
```

but now

> For MediaWiki 1.17 and above, use ResourceLoader modules.
>
> $out->addModules( array( /*modules*/ ) );

I could not make it work and don't find any examples of this.

[ResourceLoader description](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader)

[Default_modules description](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Default_modules)

Maybe I have to use `mw.loader.load` module, but I have no idea how to do it. Help me, please, and sorry for my english.

P.s. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886843/2936295) solution work, but is not right. Need solution with used ResourseLoader. (c)IMHO

Comment: There is no way where you can load external script by ResourseLoader. I wrote my own extension to do that. Better use solution from my answer. И у тебя в коде яваскрипт вставлен в пхп. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution was simple (it looks like [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712308/2nd) solution):

```
//LocalSettings.php
...
# Assign my functions to hook

$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] ='onBeforePageDisplay';

function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin )
{
    $script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"></script><script>var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": true }</script>';
    $out->addHeadItem("wowhead script", $script);
    return true;
};
```

This way look better then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886843/2936295), because it work with OutputPage directly (after parsing).

Comment: This results in poor performance. You should use [ResourceLoader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader).