# Adding external JavaScripts to MediaWiki 1.28

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mediawiki

In my current 1.25.1 MediaWiki setup, I have a lot of external JavaScrips like bxslider, qtip, datatables, etc. embedded into the header through a very intrusive way.

I simply added

```
$out->addHeadItem('danalytics','<script src="https://aionpowerbook.com/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script><link href="https://aionpowerbook.com/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'.bxslider\').bxSlider({
captions: true,
auto: ($(".bxslider li").length > 1) ? true: false,
pager: ($(".bxslider li").length > 1) ? true: false,
speed: 6000,
infiniteLoop: true,
});});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'.bxslidermap\').bxSlider(
);});
</script>
');
```

and the rest of the scripts into SkinMonoBook.php just after

```
$out->addStyle( $this->stylename . '/IE70Fixes.css', 'screen', 'IE 7' );
```

I know I wasn't supposed to touch core files, but it worked, and I was fine with it.

Anyway, recently I have been trying to update the MediaWiki software to 1.28.0 but no matter how I try to implement all the JavaScripts back, I get

```
jQuery is not defined
$ is not defined
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I have no idea what is wrong.

I tried this:
[How to add external <script> to <head> section for all mediawiki pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907743/how-to-add-external-script-to-head-section-for-all-mediawiki-pages)

Didn't work. This was kinda obvious as the MediaWiki's jquery is loaded at the bottom (I think?) but even after adding jquery library before any of my JS it would only work sometimes.

I also use the PageDisqus extension so I thought I would just copy/paste my external JavaScripts into the PageDisqus' code. That extension also loads javascrips on every page, and it seems to always work so I thought why not.
But again sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

here is an example:

https://aionpowerbook.com/pb_new/index.php?title=Main_Page

the slider at the top only sometimes loads, sometimes I need to do a hard refresh to make it load but usually on one browser it works, on another I keep getting "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

Here I also tried adding my own jquery before anything else but nope, still getting

$(...).bxSlider is not a function

from time to time.

Any help will be appreciated as I am out of ideas here.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader

Answer (score 1):

As of MediaWiki 1.26, all of MediaWiki's JavaScript is loaded asynchronously [[1](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.26#New_features)]; so, if you do not load all of your code through the ResourceLoader **and** declare dependencies, you have no guarantee that jQuery (or anything else) will be available at the time you load your code. This is probably why your code fails. You can try one of the following:

1. Use `mw.loader.load()` to load your external code; I'm not sure that will be enough.
2. Load your code in `MediaWiki:Common.js` (a page inside the wiki).
3. A better approach, in my opinion, would be to create an extension to load all of your code - declare the pieces of it as ResourceLoader modules and load them. As @Tgr said, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Variant 2 worked for me.

In general https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Core_modules#mw.loader.using would be a good solution for this. But at the moment it doesn't accept URLs and thus external scripts. At https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T27962 two possible workarounds are given.